# How to change registration requirement for user ID in chat function

Tags: quickblox

Hi when I run the sample chat function provided by quickblox, it contains several built-in limitation for username registration, for example, I need to have a certain number of characters or type of characters in order to register. I'm wondering which files contain those registration and display of error messages (I only found a class called "errors" in SignUpViewController ) and how do I change those limitations?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

- Sign Up & then Sign In with email
- Sign Up & then Sign In with login - Login field should contain alphanumeric and punctuation characters only

Is it OK? Or you have problem with other User's field?